# Getting Rabbitmq HeartBeat Exception

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amqp

I am facing one issue with rabbitmq, that it terminate the connection with below exception

```
 {"message":"com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; cause: com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 60 seconds"}
```

so I am using following configuration for it:-

1. Rabbitmq docker on aws ec2-instance1 with t2_small server.
2. Services which are facing this issue are running on aws ec2-instance2 with t2-small server.
3. Set following configuration for rabbitmq

> ```
>   factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
>     factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(1000);
>     factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(60);
> ```

I just not able to understand what can be the reason for getting this type of error, how can we resolve this issue.

Also I found below logs from the service which was trying to connect with rabbitmq

> {"log":"Caught an exception during connection recovery!\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.632851865Z"}
>   {"log":"java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.633374123Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.633666158Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.633935828Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.634170787Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.63440824Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.634625637Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.635038038Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.635172903Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:34)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.635369445Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverConnection(AutorecoveringConnection.java:435)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.635639932Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.beginAutomaticRecovery(AutorecoveringConnection.java:407)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.63584649Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.access$000(AutorecoveringConnection.java:53)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.636051142Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection$1.shutdownCompleted(AutorecoveringConnection.java:352)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.636233667Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.636899252Z"}
>   {"log":"\u0009at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:576)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.637183801Z"}

Comment: How often does this happen, and what is your network layout? The error indicates it is losing the route to the server.

Comment: Quite often I get this error, but couldn't get why its coming.

Comment: The error indicates it is losing the route to the server. @theMayer could you please explain it.

Comment: java.net.NoRouteToHostException

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find searching around, seems the connection could have been closed by the AWS load-balancers.
Could you try modifying your configuration as follows:

`factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(30);`

And see if it resolves your issue?

Comment: No, I have not tried with this configuration, I'll try to do that, but what would be the effect of reducing the time to 30

Comment: please suggest, how load-balancer can close the connection?

Comment: @Isaac - if the connection is being interrupted by a load balancer (a bigger question would be why would you have a load balancer sitting between a client and rabbitmq server) - then this might prevent it from falsely detecting a dropped connection.  I am not optimistic this is the issue though.

Comment: @theMayer I haven't configured the load balancer b/w the clients and rabbitmq

Comment: So there is a load balancer? Get rid of it and see what happens.

Comment: I haven't configure load balancer b/w client and rabbitmq. so i don't think thats an issue right??

Comment: @Isaac my answer was based on a search with similar issue reported for a rabbitmq use. To confirm (or infirm) whether it matches your case, could you elaborate on your general setup?

Comment: do you want me to elaborate infra setup

Comment: @Olivier do you think that, it can be issue of infra setup as I am using t2_small server for rabbitmq and there are 8 more services running on same instance.

Comment: @Isaac issue with ressources availability can't be evaluated just based on the server instance, best would be to check the system load. Single CPU seems quite low for so many services though. Coming back to my prior request, could you indicate where the rabbitmq clients are located?

Comment: @Olivier sorry for late reply,  I some what found the issue, at t2_small instance, we were running 9 services and rabbitmq  as well and apart from it we were running 6-7 service on another t2_small instance and these services are connected to  same rabbitmq.

Comment: So initially the services were able to run because at startup of service anyone does not send any message, when someone work in that environment, messages got published and consumed, and after some days the rabbitmq stop all channels to do some mnesia work. at that time no service able to connect with rabbitmq that when I get heartbeatexception stating that the connection is closed.